Changing from 4/4 to 6/8 note value vs beat
Often, when a time signature changes from 4/4 to 6/8 (or 4/4 to 12/8, etc.) there is a marking above the staff signifying that the quarter note = dotted quarter note.
Sometimes, this marking is not present. In these cases, is it assumed that quarter note = dotted quarter note?
When composing/arranging is it best practice to always mark this or do performers assume the beat conversion?

The notation is provided because there can't always be a safe assumption. I've been in groups that have argued over which way to go.

There are three fairly likely options: the bar length may remain constant, or the beat, or the note lengths.  (In common cases, two of those will probably coincide.)  (Alternatively, it might be most appropriate to change to a tempo not directly related to anything that came before…)  I think the default assumption would probably be to preserve the note lengths (e.g. crotchet = crotchet) — but there's enough variation that it'd be much safer to mark your intent.


In these cases, is it assumed that quarter note = dotted quarter note?

Not necessarily.  You always have to make a decision based on the information present in the score along with the historical context, the capabilities of the performers, the performance context, and probably other factors as well.  An explicit proportional indication of the relationship between the two time signatures is just one of many possible pieces of information that can be present.
Other notable possibilities include less precise tempo indications such as "allegretto" or "molto lento" or even "slightly faster"; there could also be more precise information in the form of a numerical metronome marking.
If there's really nothing at all, try keeping the eighth notes constant, try making the dotted quarter equal to the previous quarter or to the previous half note, and find what works best for you (which may well be one of those proportions but "slightly faster" or "slightly slower").  If you have colleagues or a teacher or anyone else you can ask, do so.  They may have some insight into why the piece -- one section or the other -- might work better at a slower or faster tempo than you are using.

When composing/arranging is it best practice to always mark this or do performers assume the beat conversion?

If you think it's important, you should mark it.  There will always be someone who makes assumptions other than those you assume they'll make.
